# Getting tkinter dialog to notify the user that their input is invalid

Tags: python, tkinter, dialog

I was wondering how you get the tkinter to notify the user if their input is invalid. When they input a negative integer or something that's not an integer, a dialog would pop up and say that their input is invalid. It would then let the user know and then it would let the user go back to the program. I've got the 2nd part working, but I'm getting some errors when I try to do the invalid input popup. It also pops up 2 windows as well which I have no idea why.

Code in question:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk





class TimeConverterUI():


    def __init__(self):


        #main functions
        self.root_window = Tk()
        self.root_window.geometry('400x150')
        self.root_window.title('Seconds Converter')
        self.text()
        self.quitValue=tk.Toplevel()
        self.invalidinputDialog=tk.Toplevel()
        self.calculate_button()
        self.quit_button()
        self.root_window.wait_window()


    def text(self):

        #label for seconds text along with the grid for it
        row_label = tkinter.Label(
              master = self.root_window, text = 'Seconds: ')

        row_label.grid( row = 0, 
                           sticky = tkinter.W)

        self.secondsEntry = Entry(master = self.root_window)
        self.secondsEntry.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

        #label for converted time along with the grid
        convert_label = tkinter.Label(
              master = self.root_window, text = 'Converted Time(H:M:S): ')

        convert_label.grid(row=1)

        self.result = Entry(master= self.root_window)
        self.result.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

    def calculate_button(self):

        #calculate button along with the placement
        quit = Button(self.root_window, text = "Calculate", command = self.calculate)
        quit.grid(row = 3, column = 0, columnspan = 3, pady=20,
                  sticky = tkinter.W)

    def calculate(self):

        try:

            #divides the seconds into minutes
            m,s = divmod(int(self.secondsEntry.get()),60)

            #divides the minutes into hours and returns h:m:s format
            h,m = divmod(m,60)

            c= ("%d:%02d:%02d" % (h, m, s))

            #after displaying the result, if the user wants to calculate again, deletes
            #previous result and recalculates

            self.result.delete(0,END)

            self.result.insert(0,c)



        except ValueError:

            #if user enters an input that's not an integer, exception is placed
            #d= 'Invalid Input'


            self.invalidinputDialog()
    def invalidinputDialog(self):

        self.invalidValue = tk.Toplevel()
        messageLabel = tk.Label(master=self.invalidValue,
                                text="Invalid Input.").grid(row=0,column=0)
        invalidContinue = tk.Button(master=self.invalidValue, text='Close',
                                    command = self.invalidValue.destroy).grid(row=1,column=1)

        self.result.delete(0,END)
        self.result.insert(0,d)

    def quit_button(self):

        #button for grid
        quit = Button(self.root_window, text = "Quit", command = self.quitDialog)
        quit.grid(row = 3, column = 3, columnspan = 3, pady=20,
                  sticky = tkinter.E)

    def quitDialog(self):

        self.quitValue = tk.Toplevel()
        messageLabel = tk.Label(master=self.quitValue,
                                text="Are you sure you want to quit?").grid(row=0,column=0)
        #closes both the main window and the message window
        continueButton = tk.Button(master=self.quitValue,text='Continue',
                                command=self.root_window.destroy).grid(row=1,column=2)
        #lets the user go back to previous screen if they cancel
        cancelButton = tk.Button(master=self.quitValue,text='Cancel',
                                command=self.quitValue.destroy).grid(row=1,column=1)
    def quit(self) -> bool:

        #quits the program and shell is refreshed
        self.root_window.destroy()
        return True





if __name__ == '__main__':

    convert=TimeConverterUI()
```

Here's where the problem lies.

```
def calculate(self):

    try:

        #divides the seconds into minutes
        m,s = divmod(int(self.secondsEntry.get()),60)

        #divides the minutes into hours and returns h:m:s format
        h,m = divmod(m,60)

        c= ("%d:%02d:%02d" % (h, m, s))

        #after displaying the result, if the user wants to calculate again, deletes
        #previous result and recalculates

        self.result.delete(0,END)

        self.result.insert(0,c)



    except ValueError:

        #if user enters an input that's not an integer, exception is placed
        #d= 'Invalid Input'


        self.invalidinputDialog()
def invalidinputDialog(self):

    self.invalidValue = tk.Toplevel()
    messageLabel = tk.Label(master=self.invalidValue,
                            text="Invalid Input.").grid(row=0,column=0)
    invalidContinue = tk.Button(master=self.invalidValue, text='Close',
                                command = self.invalidValue.destroy).grid(row=1,column=1)

    self.result.delete(0,END)
    self.result.insert(0,d)
```

Comment: U can use messagebox or a customer toplevel messagebox

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to simply tell the user the input was invalid you can do

```
from tkinter import messagebox

messagebox.showinfo("Title", "Input invalid.")
```

Messagebox does need to be imported separately from tkinters main library.

That being said you need to import tkinter only once. You are currently importing tkinter 3 times with:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
```

instead you should use:

```
import tkinter as tk
```

you can use this for most of tkinter methods. You just need to use the prefix `tk.` on your widgets.

examples `tk.Entry()`, `tk.Label()`, `tk.Text()` and so on.

As for your extra blank windows that are opening they are coming from your `__init__` portion of your class.

```
class TimeConverterUI():


    def __init__(self):

        self.quitValue=tk.Toplevel() # causing an empty toplevel window to open in init
        self.invalidinputDialog=tk.Toplevel() # causing an empty toplevel window to open in init
```

You do not need to set up the toplevel ahead of time. You can simply create it in a method when you need one.

Comment: Oh that worked! There's still an additional window when I run the code that has nothing on it. Could it be from self.quitValue=tk.Toplevel()?

Comment: If you are getting an unexpected window then it is most likely from an extra instance of `Tk()` or a miss use of `Toplevel()`

Comment: @Accelerate looking at your code the issues is from your `__init__` section in the TimeCoinverterUI class. You do not need to define the toplevel windows here. This is what is opening blank windows.

Comment: In fact you do not need to use toplevel at all in your program. Everything can be done with different types of messageboxes and if statements. So you will most likely need to remove any instance of `toplevel` and replace it with either `messagebox.askquestion` or `messagebox.showinfo`

Comment: Yeah, I removed the toplevel part of the code and the code ran perfectly! Thanks

Comment: @Accelerate if my answer is the solution you were looking for please consider selecting the check box next to my answer to indicate your problem has been solved. Thanks and happy coding!